# How do I implement Disqus in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, disqus

I'm in the middle of specifying the build/buy trade-offs for a public website and have hit a rather interesting avenue.

#### Background

Part of the design of the website is to incorporate comments against a set of different 'items' which obviously have their own IDss. (i.e. /recipes/23 or equipment/16 etc, etc).

Initially, i had specified a comments system with tags. However, the project sponsor has come back and asked if it would be easy to incorporate Disqus into the mix. I've used this before with Joomla (never in .NET) and think that it'll be a great idea as the comments are automatically distrubuted via the usual social network mediums by default.

#### Question

Is it fairly painless to set up an implementation of Disqus on ASP.NET MVC that works seamlessly?  Are there tutorials or examples of a working Disqus solution in ASP.NET MVC? I've seen [this example](http://www.graytechnology.com/Blog/post/Integrate-Disqus-into-your-site-using-JavaScript.aspx) and have [read the documentation](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/js/) so far.

Comment: george, thanks for the edit - makes it stand out much better.. nice one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm electing to use the async JavaScript load approach (as opposed to using the fullblown API methods). here's how simple it is using this in ASPNET MVC (It also works for ASP.NET):

From [the documentation](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/js/):

```
<!-- add the div to receive the comments via ajax -->
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>

<!-- the required javascript link to disqus -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'mydisqusname';

    // Question pour XWiki : ici il faut que je configure un identifier
    // c'est comme un sujet de Mail. Il faudrait que je mette par exemple
    // l'url de la page XWiki afin que les commentaires soient regroupes

    // ensemble par article. Bref est ce que vous pouvez me mettre un ID ?

    var disqus_identifier = 'comments-league-<%= Html.Encode(Model.ID) %>';
    var disqus_url = '<%= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url %>';
    // using disqus_developer = 1 helps to debug to localhost etc..
    var disqus_developer = 1;


    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';

        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: After reading this post, I created an HtmlHelper for Disqus that might be worthwhile sharing and maybe getting your comments and suggestions on

http://www.pieterg.com/Post/HtmlHelperextensionmethodforDisqus

Comment: PieterG - strangely enough, I did a similar thing shortly after this post :) the only difference was that i referenced my disqus_shortname from a config class, rather than passing it in via the helper. the disqus_identifier was passed as a param. I like the simplicity of the helper approach. great minds think alike. i also made a similar helper for the intensedebate comments system

Comment: Nice work guys. After I created a custom thread using a partial view with ajax it got a bit messy with likes/unlikes passing both elements to a helper made me re-think my avenue. This is much easier.

Answer (score 16):

Aparrently there is a wonderful nuget package for Disqus.

```
Install-Package Disqus.Helper
```

And then it's as easy as sticking this in your view, section, or partial view somewhere...

```
@Disqus {
     Disqus.Initialize("YourForumShortName")
}
@Discus.ShowComments("PageIdentifierOfYourChoice")
```

http://disqusforwebpages.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: You bet...I love how simple that is!

Answer (score 3):

If you are OK with having the disqus branding, the javascript API call is the way to go. If you need to have a deeper integration -- or need to do things like ensure your comments stay with your site -- you might want to check out the little library I wrote called [disqussharp](http://disqussharp.codeplex.com/) -- its a fairly complete wrapper around v 1.1 of the disqus API and can be used for lots of things.

Comment: Wyatt - what a timely post indeed then. i'll check that out right now. thanks

Comment: +1 - i see that you've got a unit test suite with the lib. i would deerly love to see an mvc implementation with a simple set of core methods in action. is that do-able at all??

Comment: Kinda pressed for time at the moment so I couldn't bang one out immediately. But I think the coding example you seek is in the tests already -- pay attention to DisqusServiceTests.cs, it has all the meaty writes and reads.

Comment: wyatt - completely understood. i'll grab a proper peek at DisqusServiceTests.cs and see where it takes me. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Here's a copule of extesion methods that target both Disqus and IntenseDebate:

firstly, the Disqus helper (with a nod to PieterG):

```
/// <summary>
/// Display Comments for Post
/// </summary>
/// <param name="html"></param>
/// <param name="postIdentifier"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static MvcHtmlString DisqusScript(this HtmlHelper html, string postIdentifier)
{
    var commentsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var id = Config.DisqusId; // get the Disqus id from config file
    var devMode = Config.DevMode; // get the devmode ('0' or '1') from config file

    commentsBuilder.Append("<div id=\"disqus_thread\"></div>");

    commentsBuilder.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    commentsBuilder.Append("var disqus_shortname = '" + id + "';");
    commentsBuilder.Append("var disqus_identifier = '" + postIdentifier + "';");
    commentsBuilder.Append("var disqus_url = '" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url + "';");
    commentsBuilder.Append("var disqus_developer = '" + devMode + "';");

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    commentsBuilder.Append("(function () {");
    commentsBuilder.Append("var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;");
    commentsBuilder.Append("dsq.src = 'http://" + id + ".disqus.com/embed.js';");

    commentsBuilder.Append("(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);");
    commentsBuilder.Append("})();");
    commentsBuilder.Append("</script>");

    commentsBuilder.Append("<noscript>");
    commentsBuilder.Append("Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href=\"http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript\">comments");
    commentsBuilder.Append("powered by Disqus.</a>");
    commentsBuilder.Append("</noscript>");
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(commentsBuilder.ToString());
}
```

and then the intensedebate version:

```
/// <summary>
/// Display Comments for Post
/// </summary>
/// <param name="html"></param>
/// <param name="postIdentifier"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static MvcHtmlString IntenseDebateScript(this HtmlHelper html, string postIdentifier)
{
    var commentsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var id = Config.IntenseDebateId; // get the IntenseDebate id from config file

    // js variables for embedded wrapper script
    commentsBuilder.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    commentsBuilder.Append("var idcomments_acct = '" + id + "';");
    commentsBuilder.Append("var idcomments_post_id = '" + postIdentifier + "';");
    commentsBuilder.Append("var idcomments_post_url = '" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url + "';");
    commentsBuilder.Append("</script>");

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    commentsBuilder.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" ");
    commentsBuilder.Append("src = 'http://www.intensedebate.com/js/genericCommentWrapperV2.js'>");
    commentsBuilder.Append("</script>");

    // add the target span for the comments
    commentsBuilder.Append("<span id='IDCommentsPostTitle' style='display:none'></span>");

    commentsBuilder.Append("<noscript>");
    commentsBuilder.Append("Please enable JavaScript to view the IntenseDebate comments");
    commentsBuilder.Append("</noscript>");
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(commentsBuilder.ToString());
}
```

usage in either case:

```
// for intensedebate
<%=Html.IntenseDebateScript("comments-id-that-i-can-use") %>

//and for disqus
<%=Html.DisqusScript("another-comments-id-that-i-can-use") %>
```

enjoy...

Comment: silly question here what is `Config` getting error for this variable :(

Comment: hey there. thr `Config` variable came from (in that version), the Disqus javascript file (`disqus.com/embed.js`). to be honest, i haven't looked at this in a while, so you'd have to look at the api in disqus to see if `Config` is still exposed. should be easy to tweak once you understand the disqus api requirements. sorry to not be more helpful